# Custom draw cell focused rectangle

Tags: devexpress, xtragrid

I have one Xtrgrid with first three columns are CustomDrawn. If I select the cells in the non custom drawn column it is showing Focus rectangle. But is not the case when I select the custom drawn column cells. It is not showing any Focus rectangle. Is there any way to show focus rectangle on custom drawn cells as well? I tried with the following
 code, but it is not working.

```
if(view.focusedcolumn == e.column && view.FocusedRowHandle == e.rowhandle)
{
    if(!view.IsEditing)
e.cache.Paint.DrawFocusRectangle(e.cache.graghics, e.bounds, e.GetForeColore(), e.BackColore();
}
```

[image]

Comment: try show more of your "paint" code.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution to this problem from the below link.
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q400321